# Change installed python path

Tags: centos, python

I am not able to install any new packages in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` path as the drive is full. So I want to transfer python2.7 to `/app/` folder with ample space. How do I do that? I am using CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you create a symlink?

```
mkdir /app/python2.7/site-packages
mv /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/* /app/python2.7/site-packages
ln -s /app/python2.7/site-packages /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

What you are doing basically is moving `/site-packages` to `/app/` and then creating a shortcut in `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` so that it points to the location in `/app/`

---

Another method you can try instead is use virtual environments.

First install virtualenv:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Then, create a virtual environment in `/app/`

```
cd /app/
virtualenv myenv
```

This will create a folder `/app/myenv` and will have python executables inside.

```
source /app/myenv/bin/activate
```

This will activate the virtualenv. You can then install all packages in the virtualenv which will be stored inside `/app/myenv`
To get out of your virtualenv just type and enter `deactivate`

> I believe this is a cleaner solution to your problem as you are not messing with your python installation files.
>
> The downside is that you will have to activate and deactivate your virtualenv every time.

Comment: so I will be transferring only the site-packages and not the whole python code? Any new packages i install will be saved in /app/python2.7/site-packages

Comment: -r in mv -r is not working. Can I know why you used that?

Comment: sorry. typo you don't need `-r` for `mv`. it's needed for `cp`.